# Getting a value from a particular dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
months = [
    {'id':'001','date':'January'},
    {'id':'002','date':'February'},
    {'id':'003','date':'March'},
    {'id':'004','date':'April'},
    {'id':'005','date':'May'},
    {'id':'006','date':'June'},
    {'id':'007','date':'July'},
    {'id':'008','date':'August'},
    {'id':'009','date':'September'},
    {'id':'010','date':'October'},
    {'id':'011','date':'November'},
    {'id':'012','date':'December'},
]
```

If the user enters the month as January, he should get the ID as 001.

I tried this, but it returns me a list of Months only.

```
res = [ mon['date'] for mon in months]
```

I need the id directly from the key itself. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the month as the key in a dictionary:

```
res = {mon['date']: mon['id'] for mon in months}
print(res['January'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You convert what you have to a dict that maps from months to ids

```
new_dict = {item['date']: item['id'] for item in months}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will work for you.

```
month_name = input("Enter month name.")
dic = next(item for item in months if item["date"] == month_name)
id = dic["id"]
print(id)
```

I have tested this code on my local, and it works good.

Answer (score 0):

it should be id instead of date

```
res = [ mon['id'] for mon in months]
```

Comment: I need date only and not id, as that is my particular requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` to filter within the list comprehension:

```
id = [m['id'] for m in months if m['date'] == 'January'][0]
```